# Text rotation with google chrome using css

Tags: css, transform

I gave definition for the class to display the text vertically, but it wont works with chrome!

Here with i attached the image

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You might try the following CSS:

```
{
    transform:rotate(7deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(90deg); /* IE 9 */
    -moz-transform:rotate(90deg); /* Firefox */
    -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transform:rotate(90deg); /* Opera */
}
```

I have a demo from a while back that may be of use to you also - http://codepen.io/lukeocom/pen/mHnvl

Comment: Sorry, but this works only on IE. And not working on Chrome